# Reactjs Pattern form validation not returning error message

Tags: reactjs, redux

The code below shows how I validate **ReactJs** form by ensuring that form submission is not empty and it works fine. Now I want to also ensure that the form input will only contain alphabets. To this effect, I have resorts to pattern method hence this code `pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"`
Below is how am checking it but its not returning any error message if the user enters any value that is not alphabets

```
 <div className={'form-group' + (submitted  &&!user.firstName ? ' has-error' : 'pattern')}>
 {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">The firstName can only contain the letters a-z or A-Z</div>
                        }
</div>
```

Here is the working Code. It does validation by ensuring that firstname is not empty. With Pattern method within the input, it
check to ensure that the firstname contains only alphabets but the problem is that it does not show error message when a user
enters a values that is not alphabets.

```
<form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="firstName"  
pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />



 <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
 {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                        }
</div>


/*
// Output error message if firstname is not alphabets 

 <div className={'form-group' + (submitted  &&!user.firstName ? ' has-error' : 'pattern')}>
 {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">The firstName can only contain the letters a-z or A-Z</div>
                        }
</div>

*/

                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button">Register</button>


                    </div>
                </form>
```

For example, Below is how I achieve the same purpose  in **angular 6**

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="username"
            [(ngModel)]="login.username"
            #loginUsername="ngModel"
            required
            pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$">

      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="loginUsername.errors?.required  && loginUsername.touched">
        The username is required
      </span>
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="loginUsername.errors?.pattern && loginUsername.touched">
        The username can only contain the letters a-z or A-Z
      </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably **unconditionally** save input value to state in `handleChange`. Invalid state must be read separately (explicitely) from event (real DOM).

You can prevent storing wrong values to state using condition within handler, f.e.

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState( {
    name: e.target.validity.valid ? e.target.value : ""
  })
}
```

This will block any non valid characters (from start). **Drawbacks:** It will clear the whole valid string on attempt to insert invalid character.

Of course you can set additional value for error state ... and use it for conditional rendering (style/hint).

Why not using `Formik`? Handling 'low level', 'raw' html errors and manual validation can be an overkill. Is this a strict requirement?